# How to get arduino port with python

Tags: python, linux, serial-port, arduino, raspberry-pi

I'm developing an embedded project and I need to connect Arduino and Raspberry pi because I want to control Arduino with Raspberry Pi over the serial port. My question is how can I get the Arduino port in Linux dynamicaly with python?

My python program will loop sending commands to Arduino and I don't want to lose communication if someone connects and disconnects the Arduino.

Thanks for any help.
Zulin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
def get_serial_port():
    return "/dev/"+os.popen("dmesg | egrep ttyACM | cut -f3 -d: | tail -n1").read().strip()
```

Then you can just connect with arduino doing:

```
device = serial.Serial(get_serial_port(), baudrate=9600, timeout=3)
```

(assuming you are using the default rate 9600, you can just change the params...)

Comment: os.popen is depreciated since python 2.6, the subprocess module should be used

Answer (score 3):

1st install [Pyserial](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/)

if you have connected you arduino with you pc, you can see all serial message:

```
sudo screen /dev/ttyAMC0
```

now come to python to control arduino:

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600)
ser.write("something")           # this will write "your stuff" to Arduino serial.
```

now using Cprogram you can read from serial what the input is. And you can command your arduino using python

C pogram to read from Serial and write to serial:

```
char a[10];
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
}
void loop()
{
  if(Serial.available()>0)
  {
      Serial.readBytes(a,10);
      Serial.println(a);
  }
}
```